# Acceso a metodos mediante clase padre

Tags: c#, clase

lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:
Tengo unos objetos:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string nombre{ get; set; }
   
}
public class Articulo
{
    public string id{ get; set; }
    public string descripcion{ get; set; }
   
}
```

I una clase consulta que implementarà los metodos Obtener e Insertar tanto para clientes como para articulos.
No tendria problema para consumir estos metodos de una forma similar a:

```
consulta.Obtener(Cliente cliente)
```

Pero me interesaría y no se me ocurre como poder estructurarlo de forma que pudiera consumir los métodos de la siguiente forma

```
Cliente cli = Consulta.Clinte.obtener();
```

¿Podéis guiarme por favor?

Comment: Entonces la clase cliente deberia tener un metodo obtener...asi sea implementando una interfaz, o heredando de otra clase que tenga el metodo obtener y esta lo use o lo sobreescriba...

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es generar una clase consulta que sea genérica, eso seria mejor... O no sé que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente.

Comment: Tendrías que crearte una interfaz IConsulta con un método obtener por ejemplo y hacer que Cliente y Articulo hereden de ella e implementen dicho método, de esta forma podrías llamar a la interfaz IConsulta _consulta.Obtener() y dependiendo de la instancia a la asignación se determina hacia qué clase apuntar